# How to set a default value for Simple hierarchical select?

Tags: forms, taxonomy-terms

I tried to implement `hook_form_alter` in order to pass default value to [Simple hierarhical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) views exposed filter.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $tid = get_tid_from_termalias (arg(1)); // here I get tid
  $form_state['input']['field_sity1_tid'] = (!empty($tid)) ? $tid : 'All'; 
  $form_state['field_sity1_tid']['#value'] = (!empty($tid)) ? $tid : 'All'; 
  $form['field_sity1_tid']['#default_value'] = (!empty($tid)) ? $tid : 'All';
  $form['field_sity1_tid']['#value'] = (!empty($tid)) ? $tid : 'All';
}
```

I see that shs.js creates 2 selects, one hidden and one shown. My code changes only the value in the hidden select while second select always remains 'All'. How to change the visible select's default value?

Comment: how can I set a default set of options for the shs dropdown select list?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, That's a challenge to set default with Simple hierarchical select using form alter.

As they are handling options to taxonomy in js.

But we have another way to set default value for the field. Passing in URL.
Like : http://localhost/drupal/demo-view?field_test_tid=1

Hope this will help.
Just trying other way.